# How to exclude table and class from background color?

Tags: css

I would like to add a background color to my page but leave the table background (the table appears on submit) and the inside of the box to the left of it (which has a class of .inputs) white.

I tried adding the following to my CSS, but it doesn't do anything:

```
body:not(.inputs) {
  background-color: #c3d6de;
}

body:not(table) {
  background-color: #c3d6de;
}
```

Please view my current code for reference: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/nataliecardot/pen/VQRrgQ)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem with your CSS. When you do `body:not(table)`, you are specifying these styles to be applied to any body that is not a table. This doesn't make sense since a body element cannot also be a table element. The same thing applies for `body:not(.inputs)`. Since you want to target all **descendant** elements of `body` that are not `table` or `.inputs`, you would need to put a space between `body` and `:not` like this:

```
body :not(.inputs) {
  background-color: #c3d6de;
}

body :not(table) {
  background-color: #c3d6de;
}
```

This would target all elements that are not `table` or `.inputs`, and that are **descendants** of `body`.

However, you might run into problems with your approach because if the table is inside another element, the background element of the containing element will show through the table since default background of tables is transparent. I would suggest explicitly giving your table a white background, like this:

```
body {
  background-color: #c3d6de;
}

table {
  background-color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add background color to Body and tabel as well. Like this.

```
body {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial;
  background-color : #c3d6de;
}
.pixel-canvas {
  background-color : white;
}
```